# Is a person serving a property owner with notice of a lawsuit excempt from trespassing charges?

Tags: united-states, oregon, litigation, trespassing, service-of-process

If John sues Bob, and he walks past Bob's "POSTED - NO TRESPASSING" sign up to his door to serve him notice of the lawsuit, Bob says "Get off my property!" before realizing why John is there, and John stays long enough to give the papers to Bob, is John trespassing?

Comment: You should also consider: If John goes away as told, has Bob been legally served? If Bob suffers disadvantages because he doesn’t read the notice is that his own fault?

Comment: FWIW, there is a whole specific body of law about walking from a public street to the front door of a residence, even though it isn't very general.

Comment: @ohwilleke does that apply if the residence is on a relatively long private road?

Comment: @Someone It's a long, involved detailed case law that also goes into distinctions between public officials like sheriffs and mailmen and firemen v. private common carriers v. ordinary people. Basically, public policy concerns have steadily eroded the ability to declare someone to be trespassing on the direct route to your front door. For process servers, the alternative is substituted service.